# Transform an array of dictionaries and store into Realm in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, mapping, realm

I have a Json type of an Array of dictionaries, but I can only store the first dictionary which has the type "rent":

```
"prices": [
    {
        "type": "rent",
        "currency": "MY",
        "min": 1000000,
        "max": 5000000
    },
    {
        "type": "buy",
        "currency": "MY",
        "min": 4000000,
        "max": 5000000
    }
],
```

So, in Listing.Swift, I call transform class to convert it into dictionary:

**Listing.swift**

```
_price <- (map["prices"], ListingPriceTransform())
```

**ListingPriceTransform.swift**

```
class ListingPriceTransform: TransformType {
    typealias Object = ListingPrice
    typealias JSON = [[String: AnyObject]]

    func transformFromJSON(value: AnyObject?) -> Object? {
        guard let jsonDictionariesArray = value as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return nil }

        for object in jsonDictionariesArray {
            return ListingPrice.createModel(object)
        }

        return ListingPrice.createModel(Object)
    }

    func transformToJSON(value: Object?) -> JSON? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

**ListingPrice.swift**

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    type <- map["type"]
    currency <- map["currency"]
    minPrice <- (map["min"], IntTransform())
    maxPrice <- (map["max"], IntTransform())
}
```

So, I am failing to save probably in ListingPriceTransform (for loop) to get dictionaries from array before passing into Map in ListingPrice.swift.

Comment: You might need to provide some more information. Can you set a breakpoint and confirm you're properly getting an array of dictionaries in the first line of `transformFromJSON`? Also, what exactly does `createModel` do?